# iOS API to post to instagram stories

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, user-stories

I was searching if there is any way I can post to instagram stories from a third-party app. Looking on the instagram developers documentation, I couldn't find any information about this.

Also, as I've seen on the instagram documentation, from iOS I can only post photos to the instagram feed, but no videos. Is there any way to post videos?

Comment: There is no API for stories

Comment: I need this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instagram Story Share API is now available!

[See documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories)